# What is probability of independent events?

Tags: probability

I have N similar hard drives. There is a probability f% that any one of them will crash. What is the probability that at least two of them will crash?

Comment: A probabilistic answer will assume that HDD crashes are independent. Problem: hard drive crash probabilities are not really independent - e.g. a power surge could damage multiple hard-drives at the same time. The probability of each hard drive failing may be dependently tied to some other variable.

Comment: Let's agree they are independent :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $p=\frac f{100}$, the probability of no crash at all is $(1-p)^N$ and the probability of exactly one crash is $Np(1-p)^{N-1}$ (picke one, let it crash, let the others not crash), so the probability of two or more crashs is $$1-(1-p)^N-Np(1-p)^{N-1} = 1-(1-(N+1)p)(1-p)^{N-1}. $$